# Android - send data from Activity to NavigationDrawerFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to send some data from an activity to the NavigationDrawerFragment. Here is the code I have; most of the code was generated by Android Studio, the code I added is indicated in the comment:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

    // my code starts
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("num", 123);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    // my code ends

    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    int num = getArguments().getInt("num"); // my code
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
            }));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}
```

When I run the app I got `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`. How could I fix this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `NavigationDrawerFragment` is statically declared in your layout, it is being instantiated as the Activity is laid out - i.e., upon the call to `setContentView()` - and its `onCreateView()` method is running before your call to `setArguments()`. Furthermore, `setArguments()` cannot be called on a Fragment once it has been attached to an Activity, which is happening automatically because of the Fragment's static declaration. If you want to pass data to an already active Fragment, a simple way is to create a public method in its class, and call it on the instance after its initialization.